# Opening Attachment Crashing

Tags: c#

So my program can open attachments which are saved onto the database. It is having issues with opening microsoft documents. If that  process is unique then it'll open. If it's a duplication it'll crash. I attempted try/catch but I'm using a coroutine to show error messages and try/catch doesn't allow Yield return.

what I've tried:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> OpenAttachment()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog sfg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    string path = sfg.SelectedPath;
    byte[] bytes = AttachmentSelectedItem.FileArray;
    string Name = AttachmentSelectedItem.FileName;
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + Name, bytes);
        Process.Start(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\" + Name);
        yield return ErrorView.Show("File Is Uploaded");
    }
    catch
    {
        yield return ErrorView.Show("Please close Existing File");
    }
}
```

I'm wondering is there another method I could use which would allow me to use my Coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it doesn't crash on save because the file already exists (or is still running) and cannot overwrite it?

have you tried renaming the file if it already exists?

Comment: Not so much on save, as maybe because the first file he put there is still a running process, thus preventing him from overwriting that file?

Comment: @Flater - it may well be that

Comment: What #Flater said, Ted it's not about saving..... it's opening and i can't rename the file if it's within the database.... And how would i check if it already "exist" it's not a physical item. It's within the Temporary path

Comment: @user3276954: I didn't say that. It's still a saving issue (according to my idea), but it's caused *because* you're trying to overwrite a file that is currently running (and therefore in use and locked for writing). Either save in a different location, with a different filename, or if you want to overwrite the old file, wait until it is no longer in use.

Comment: do a `do..while` and keep changing the file name `while` it exists

Comment: That would be an option but I don't want to resort changing the file name.